# Web server to host Sencha app?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am looking to develop some web app for my Android device. Found Sencha and think it might be a good tool to try out.

I suppose I would need to find a web server to host the Sencha app to run the app? What kind of web server is needed? I suppose one that able to run HTML5, CSS, Javascript is enough?

Can anybody recommend one (free one)?

Thanks.

++++++++++++

Thanks for the answers to the above post. I am new to this stuff, so got some more follow-up and somewhat related questions:

1) I read from the Sencha site that the app can be developed locally using things like XAMPP installed on local Windows PC. Question -- Why need this local host when I can just use an external Web Host?

2) It was also mentioned that for Windows may not need XAMPP if Window's Internet Information Server (IIS) is already running. How do I know if my computer is running this and so don't need to install another local server? (I asking this because I had installed an XAMPP before on another computer and things got quite messed up and so I want to avoid doing it if possible).

3) Once I got a web host, to have an app running, I would just have to have the JS files in the web host together with the Sencha framework right? If so, then I don't understand what is meant by "Build" in the Sencha documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks M69 and Ziad for your answers.

Comment: Why are you asking the same thing in multiple questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797413/local-host-for-sencha-app-development

Comment: Oh, I thought I should close this question and ask the follow up questions separately. Sorry, new to this.

Comment: To close the question you should accept one of the best answers by clicking the green checkmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha Touch is a client side framework, therefore there are no server side requirements. That said, any web host should do.

However, I'll go ahead an make a recommendation... a LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, PHP, MySql) will work the best. Of course you can substitute any of the stack for something of your favor, this setup seems to be the most favorable. Some of my colleagues utilize Ruby/RoR instead of PHP, so as you can see it is quite flexible in terms of environment.

When searching for a hosting provider, do your research and select something that fits with your budget but still gives you the best bang for your buck. Be sure to ask them questions!

Tip: Make sure you have access to your web server's configuration file so you can add mime_types and make other mobile oriented tweaks if needed.

Answer (score 1):

First you must know that HTML5, CSS and Javascript are all front end stuff that do not count when you talk about Hosting. These are taken care of by the client agent (browser).

What really matters is your server side language: PHP, Python(Django), Ruby, etc.
So it mainly doesn't matter which framework, as much as which language that framework use.

This is a generic answer that will help you decide not only in terms of Sencha but for any other framework.

Take for instance WordPress. It uses PHP and MySQL, so first I look if my Web host supports Mysql and PHP and in general this would be enough to know that I can use if for my WordPress site.

And by the way, most Web host companies allow you to ask them questions before buying. So go ahead and question them about anything that concerns your requests.

Answer (score 1):

Sencha provides an app hosting service through its [Sencha.io](http://sencha.io) cloud services.